# Create an FB user programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to register a new user into the FB through an SDK or an API. I saw there is a way to [create test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/test-user). My use case is I want to create FB account for my application users in case they don't want one.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: It makes little sense to create a Facebook app, for people who don’t want to create their own personal Facebook account in the first place. Those people simply do not _want_ to use your app at all then, simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is not possible and if at all needed one can create test users in FB.